# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un conteo de los caracteres ingresados en un arreglo en java?

Tags: java

Me encuentro realizando un ejercicio propio, que desearía hacer un conteo de caracteres ingresados. He definido que por consola se ingrese el tamaño del arreglo y se pueda ingresar caracteres, y luego de ello quisiera hacer un conteo, para lo cual me hubiera gustado utilizar el if++. Pero creo que he llegado hasta ahí.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Variables
        char letras[]; //Arreglo
        int l;  //Tamaño del arreglo
        int a =0, b=0, c=0, d=0;
        // Leer N elementos de un vector
        System.out.print("Ingrese el tamaño del Arreglo (L): ");
        l = lectura.nextInt();
        letras = new char[l];  
        for(int i=0; i<letras.length; i++){
            System.out.print("Ingrese el valor para datos["+i+"] = ");
            letras[i] = lectura.next().charAt(0);
        }
        if(letras[i] == 'a'){
                a++;
            }
        if(letras[i] == 'b'){
            b++;
        }
        if(letras[i] == 'c'){
            c++;
        }
        if(letras[i] == 'd'){
            d++;
        }
            System.out.println("La letra 'A' se ingresó: "+a+" veces.");
            System.out.println("La letra 'B' se ingresó: "+b+" veces.");
            System.out.println("La letra 'F' se ingresó: "+c+" veces.");
            System.out.println("La letra 'J' se ingresó: "+d+" veces.");
}
```

> Tengo una pregunta aparte, es posible volver esa cantidad de números, en porcentaje? En caso que hubiera 1 en cada letra, podría mostrarse un 25% en cada uno?

Comment: Disculpa, pero no es claro cuál es tu primera pregunta. Cuál es el problema con el código? Para lo segundo, ¿porcentaje sobre el total de carácteres? O sobre las letras que estás contando (que son sólo esas cuatro)?

Comment: si tienes una pregunta aparte, hazla aparte

Comment: No hagas múltiples preguntas en una: lee [ask]. Además, pon el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten presente el cerrado de llaves,esto hara que el bucle for declarado ejecute solo el codigo dentro de las llaves

```
for(int i=0; i<letras.length; i++){//abres llaves
        System.out.print("Ingrese el valor para datos["+i+"] = ");
        letras[i] = lectura.next().charAt(0);
    }//cierras llaves
```

tus condicionales `if` evalúan si cada carácter almacenado en el `array` es igual a las siguientes letras `a b c d` sin embargo vos al imprimir haces referencia a las siguientes letras  `A B F J` mas aun en mayúscula,(ojo con la diferencia )el fragmento corregido seria el siguiente

```
for(int i=0; i<letras.length; i++){
        System.out.print("Ingrese el valor para datos["+i+"] = ");
        letras[i] = lectura.next().charAt(0);
    
    if(letras[i] == 'A'){
            a++;
        }
    if(letras[i] == 'B'){
        b++;
    }
    if(letras[i] == 'F'){
        c++;
    }
    if(letras[i] == 'J'){
        d++;
    }
}
        System.out.println("La letra 'A' se ingresó: "+a+" veces.");
        System.out.println("La letra 'B' se ingresó: "+b+" veces.");
        System.out.println("La letra 'F' se ingresó: "+c+" veces.");
        System.out.println("La letra 'J' se ingresó: "+d+" veces.");
```

si quisieras evaluar tanto mayúscula como minúscula en la misma letra,tendrías que hacer uso del conector lógico `or (||)`

```
if(letras[i] == 'A' || letras[i] == 'a'){
            a++;
        }
```

con respecto al apartado de porcentaje aplica regla de tres simple donde `l` sera el 100% por ser el total de caracteres que se ingresara

```
System.out.println("La letra 'A' se ingresó: "+a+" veces."+"porcentaje: "+(a*100.0)/l +"%");
```

Comment: ¿Dramaturgo, cómo me podría contactar contigo?

Comment: me parece que ya puedes hacer uso del [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137366/discussion-on-answer-by-dramaturgo-como-guardar-en-un-array-numeros-de-un-txt-p)